# Set Variable in Named Range (Loop)

Tags: vba, excel

I want to call named ranges with some kind of loop Lets assume i have sheet with:

2 named ranges
2 shapes
[namedrange1] is set to A1
[namedrange2] is set to A2
Range A1 value is 1
Range A2 value is 2
first shape is named shape1
second shape is named shape2

I want to do something with the shapes, for example moving them, i could do:

```
Sub moveshapes()  
ActiveSheet.Shapes("shape" & [namedrange1]).Top = Cells(3, 3).Top  
ActiveSheet.Shapes("shape" & [namedrange2]).Top = Cells(3, 3).Top  
End Sub
```

But i dont want to do it like that. What if i had like 100 shapes? I need to use some kind of loop with variable in named range NAME. I tried the code below, but it doesnt work..

```
Sub moveshapes()  
Dim i As Integer  
For i = 1 To 2  
ActiveSheet.Shapes("shape" & [namedrange & i]).Top = Cells(3, 3).Top  
Next i  
End Sub
```

Comment: Try `ActiveSheet.Shapes("shape" & Range("namedrange" & i).Value).Top = Cells(3, 3).Top`

Comment: This was what ive been missing! Thank you this works like a charm!

Comment: @Fadi One more question: Why i cannot do it with the brackets [ ] way? like: `ActiveSheet.Shapes("shape" & Range([namedrange] & i).Value).Top = Cells(3, 3).Top`

Comment: I never use brackets [ ], so i don't know :). maybe someone here can answer your question. but i think you need to post new question about this.

Comment: The brackets don't work because you don't have a range with a name of `namedrange` and, if you did, you would be appending the value of `i` to the value of the cell referred to by `namedrange`.  (So if A6 had a name of `namedrange`, and A6 contained the value `"xyz"`, and `i` was 5, then `Range([namedrange] & i)` would be equivalent to `Range("xyz" & 5)` which would be equivalent to `Range("xyz5")`.)

Comment: And in your `ActiveSheet.Shapes("shape" & [namedrange & i]).Top = Cells(3, 3).Top` example, VBA is looking for a **variable** called `namedrange` so that it can append the value of `i` to it.  And, even if you had a variable called `namedrange` that was a string containing `"namedrange"`, `[namedrange & i]` would just generate `["namedrange5"]` (assuming `i` was 5), and evaluating a string just leaves you with the string - it needs to be `[namedrange5]` in order to evaluate in a way that will retrieve a range from Excel.  (Compare `[5*4]` --> `20`, and `["5*4"]` --> `"5*4"`.)